# Hash Tables: Ransom Note - Hacker Rank in Javascript

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge

I'm preparing for an interview doing the preparation questions on Hacker Rank and I want to become better at this. Is it possible to get some feedback on this? How can I improve my code? How did you solve this question?

```js
function getCount(array){
    let counts = {}
    for(let word of array){
        let count = counts[word]
        counts[word] = count ? counts[word] + 1: 1;
    }
    return counts
}
// Complete the checkMagazine function below.

function compareNoteMag(note,mag){
    let noteKeys = Object.keys(note)
    let string = 'Yes'
    for(let key of noteKeys){
        if(!mag[key]) string = 'No'
        if(mag[key] < note[key]){
            string = 'No'
        }
    }
     console.log(string)
}

function checkMagazine(magazine, note) {
    let magazineCount = getCount(magazine);
    let noteCount = getCount(note);
    compareNoteMag(noteCount,magazineCount)
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please describe the problem being solved, and add a link to it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Performance

There are several performance issues in the posted code:

1. The loop over `noteKeys` continues even after it knows that a word is missing. It should stop.
2. The map of counts of words in the magazine is unnecessary internal storage. A likely question for discussion during an interview is "what if the magazine doesn't fit in memory, how would you change your implementation?". Food for thought.

#### Program organization

It's best when a function does one thing.
`compareNoteMag` does two: computes if there are enough words in the magazine, and prints "Yes" or "No".
This should have been a function returning `boolean`,
with an appropriate descriptive name.

#### Safety

The second `if` should have been an `else if` here:

> ```
> if(!mag[key]) string = 'No'
> if(mag[key] < note[key]){
>     string = 'No'
> }
> ```

Not only this is inefficient (the second `if` is sometimes evaluated unnecessarily), the expression in the second `if` is sometimes a comparison between `undefined` and a number, which can be confusing and lead to mistakes.

#### Naming

Some of the names could be better:

- `getCount` returns a map of *counts* (plural), so I would rename to `getCounts` (plural).
- `getCount` takes an array of words: `words` would be a natural and intuitive name instead of `array`.
- `compareNoteMag` computes the answer to print: `answer` would be a natural and intuitive name instead of `string`.

#### Technique

Instead of this:

> ```
> let count = counts[word]
> counts[word] = count ? counts[word] + 1: 1;
> ```

A common technique in JavaScript:

```
counts[word] = (counts[word] || 0) + 1;
```

#### Attention to detail

This is very minor, but I notice some sloppiness:

- Semicolons are mostly omitted but not always
- The semicolon is unnecessary at the end of `function checkMagazine(...) { ... };`
- The comment `// Complete the checkMagazine function below.` should not be there
- The common convention is to put spaces around the parentheses in `for(...){` and `if(...){`

Comment: Regarding the spaces and semicolons, is it okay to say that I will use beautify with whatever settings decided in the project in a real situation?